# Delete folders/files that are not listed in a textfile

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that read a list of paths from a text file. If the list does not include the path of the subfolders/files in the windows explorer, it will then be removed.

---

For example, in `D:\test` contains:

```
 Hi              <Directory>
 Bye             <Directory>
 Hello.txt
 cya.txt
 checkList.txt
```

So in `my checkList.txt`:(this is the list containing folders/files that shouldn't be deleted)

```
D:\test\Hi
D:\test\Hello.txt
D:\test\checkList.txt
```

---

As a result, after running the batch file, `Bye folder` and `cya.txt` will be removed.

Comment: Please note Stack Overflow is not a write-code-for-me site. You should add your code before you ask, otherwise, the question will be most likely closed for "Unclear What You Are Asking".

Comment: Plus, `checklist.txt` contains it's own name, should `checklist.txt` be removed?

Comment: Why? You said `checklist.txt` contains every file to remove - so shouldn't `checklist.txt` be removed since it's also on the list?

Comment: Oh well my fault

Comment: To the person that marked it down, I guess because you are incapable of doing this. Many might need this script in the future as it comes in handy. I myself is still currently trying to think of way in solving and will post it here once I have achieved my result

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but my best guess is that you didn't add the code. Stack Overflow is a place where people met into issues with their code. I guess the downvoter is just a passerby and may not come back anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%G in (checklist.txt) do set "str=%%~G !str!"
for /f %%G in ('dir /b /s ^| findstr /v /i "%str%"') do ECHO del "%%~G"
pause
```

Loops through files in `checklist.txt` and remove them unnecessary files. Remove `ECHO` whenever necessary.

**Edit:** I have added the `/s` flag to the `dir` command in order to show the full path for `findstr` to work.